# Codemodel does not generate static import

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

JCodeModel generates an `import` statement in place of an `import static`. For example I have a class that has `import nz.co.cloudm.cloudserv.api.pojos.core.file.attachment.Attachment.Status` instead of `import static nz.co.cloudm.cloudserv.api.pojos.core.file.attachment.Attachment.Status` so the compiler throws an error. The class `Status` is an inner enum that lives in the `Attachment` class as you can see in the import statement.

Do you know any way I can achieve an import static using code model?

Or otherwise how make the member to use the class qualified name?

```
private nz.co.cloudm.cloudserv.api.pojos.core.file.attachment.Attachment.Status status;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure codemodel has the ability to define static imports, as it's an older library.  You can use the enum though just through the `ref()` method since static imports are really just a programmer's convenience:

```
public class Tester {

    public enum Status{
        ONE, TWO;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JClassAlreadyExistsException, IOException {
        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();

        JClass ref = codeModel.ref(Status.class);

        JDefinedClass outputClass = codeModel._class("Output");

        outputClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, ref, "status", ref.staticRef(Status.ONE.name()));

        codeModel.build(new StdOutCodeWriter());
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
public class Output {
    private test.Tester.Status status = test.Tester.Status.ONE;
}
```

Comment: That line fixed my issue: JClass ref = codeModel.ref( qualified class name ); The class reference makes the member as I needed and you showed, so the import static statement is no longer required. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  There may be a better way to reference the specific enum value (Status.ONE) than using .staticRef().